# file_get_contents returns "FileName can't be empty" in a Laravel application

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am making file upload from vue.js to Laravel API.

```
onFilePicked (e) {
   const files = e.target.files
   const fr = new FileReader ()
   fr.readAsDataURL(files[0])
   fr.addEventListener('load', () => {
     let imageFile = files[0] // this is an image file that can be sent to server...
     this.submit(imageFile);
   })
 }
```

When user changes/chooses file, this function gets called, then submit function in which I got something like this:

```
this.formData = new FormData();
this.formData.append('image', imageFile);
await axios.post(url, this.formData);
```

Now, in api, I got something like this:

```
file_get_contents($request->file('image'))
```

**Problem**: This throws an exception stating that `file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty`. The real issue is that from desktop Chrome, it works fine (not throwing any exception), but from mobile Chrome, this is what happens.

I am also using Sentry Error handling and that thrown exception I talked about I receive it in Sentry. Sentry also tells me what the image looks like in request:

```
{
client_filename: IMG_20190908_131814.jpg, 
client_media_type: , 
size: 0
}
```

Comment: please check the posted data by using print_r($request->all()).

Comment: from mobile chrome, $request->file('image') is empty. from desktop chrome, it's image.

Comment: I think the data is not posted correctly. Can you check once more using this code : $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input'); $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data); print_r($raw_post_array);